# Pushing changes from View back to Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have written a custom editor in eclipse which works on XML file and displays it's content in tree format in this editor. On click of a particular row in tree I am opening a view below which will have all the information for that selected row which user can edit.

I am stuck on how to push those changes made by user in the view back to the editor so the information can be saved back to original XML.

Appreciate any help or pointers.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find the editor and call something in it to update the data. For example:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();

MyEditor myEditor = (MyEditor)editor;

// TODO call some method you define on your editor
```

where `MyEditor` is your main editor class.

You may want to use one of the other `IWorkbenchPage` `findEditor` methods to be sure you get your editor.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449..adding to it further.what I think there is no save option for View(similar to Editor) , what I can do is I can provide a save button in the view and add a listener to it where I will get hold of editor and call some method from my editor class or is there some open-edit-save mechanism present for View also similar to Editor.